# Changing namespace of Stream

Tags: c#, web-services

I've got asmx with method

```
[Webmethod]
public Ssytem.IO.Stream GetStream(string path)
{
...
}
```

and winforms  application which has webreference to this webservice.

I cannot do something on my winforms application like something:

```
var myStream= (System.IO.Stream)client.GetStream(path);
```

because i

```
Cannot cast expression "MyWinformsApp.MyService.Stream" to Stream.
```

Why is that ?

Comment: can you post more of the asmx page? because it seems the signature of the GetStream is returning MyWinformsApp.MyService.Stream instead of Sytem.IO.Stream you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a Stream via a WebMethod. If you want to return the data in the file, there are a number of options, but the most straightforward is probably:

- Read the file contents and base64 encode it.
- Return the base64 encoded data.
- On the client-side decode the data and save it back to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `MyWinformsApp.MyService.Stream` does not derive from `System.IO.Stream` ?! You are correctly prohibited from casting an object into something it isn't.

Comment: I doesn't have class Stream. I use in this webmethod System.IO.Stream